# Вся жизнь была залогом

Tags: значение-слов, пушкин

Это из «Евгения Онегина». Письмо Татьяны Лариной к Евгению Онегину. Там есть такие строки:

**Вся жизнь моя была *залогом***
Свиданья верного с тобой;
Я знаю, ты мне послан Богом,
До гроба ты хранитель мой...

Что в данном случае может означать слово *«залог»*?
Обычно, насколько я знаю, это слово употребляют в смысле каких-то ценностей, которые дают как гарантию кредита, долга, займа и т.п.

Comment: Если бы свиданья не было, не было бы и жизни.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[В словарях](http://tolkslovar.ru/z2262.html) Ушакова и Ефремовой приводится толкование слова "залог", только с разными пометами: "книжное" и "переносное":

Ушаков:

> Символ, доказательство чего-н., ручательство в чем-н. (книжн.). *Хотел
>   бы я тебе представить залог достойнее тебя, достойнее души
>   прекрасной.* Пушкин. В залог дружбы.

Ефремова:

> Доказательство, свидетельство осуществления чего-л. в будущем (перен.). *Это кольцо - залог нашей любви.*

[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3):

> **перен.** гарантия, нечто, служащее подтверждением чего-либо ◆ *Мисс Жаксон, удостоверясь, что Лиза не думала поднять её на смех,
>   успокоилась, поцеловала Лизу и в залог примирения подарила ей баночку
>   английских белил, которую Лиза приняла с изъявлением искренней
>   благодарности.* А. С. Пушкин, «Барышня-крестьянка», 1830 г.
>
> **перен.** причина, обязательное условие ◆ *Налаженный постпродажный сервис — залог лояльности клиентов.*